# How to manage large file volumes in a given directory

Tags: files

I need guidance on how to write a bash script to manage my logfiles. I use this command to `find . -name "*.log" -print |zip -m LOGFILES.zip -@` to zip the files.  I then move the zipped files manually to another dir e.g `find . -name '*.zip' -exec mv {} /dest/dir/ \;`.

I want to write a script that can:

1. Find all files older than one month move them to a new directory
2. Zip all the moved files in the new directory
3. Confirm in the new directory if all files have been moved and zipped.
4. Go back to the source directory and delete all the files older than one month.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for sharing your work. Have a look at `-mtime` and `-ctime` flags of Find, you seem to be after them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback, but i wanted to sample script whcih can do the above 4 proedures.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Please don't do all such things.

You need to use logrotate utility .. it's simple, easy and useful:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/